# Xamarin.Forms Add project reference to a portable dll

Tags: xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I need to add a reference to a portable library in the main Xamarin.Forms Project.
There isn't References folder nor Project properties form.

[image]

The library is a portable library compatible with Android, iOS and Windows Phone. It has the app logic that I don't like to put on the Xamarin Project.

The only way I see is to use referenced files to the original portable class.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Just to clarify: You have a Xamarin.Forms project (which is a PCL project in itself, let's call it project X), and a separate PCL project which has app logic (project A). You want to reference project A within project X. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, the main Xamarin.Forms Project (X) needs a reference to the logic Project Portable Class (A).

Comment: Are you using Xamarin Studio or VS? What do you mean there is no References folder?

Comment: I'm using VS2015, and I explain a litle more:
- I create a TEST solution using Xamaring.Forms
- The solution created by VS has these projects:
  - TEST
  - TEST.Droid
  - TEST.iOS
  - TEST.UWP
  - TEST.Windows
  - TEST.WindowsPhone

I want to add a TEST.logic Project with the app logic, and I need to reference it from TEST.
How can I do it?

Comment: A screenshot of relevant portion of the Solution Explorer might help to clarify...

Comment: There is a link to solutions explorer screenshot -> [link](http://www.duefectucorp.com/temp/Xamarin.Forms_Reference.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your screenshot, PairBook is a Shared Project and therefore doesn't have references or produce any output.

The code in the shared project is compiled into other projects that reference it and exists purely as a collection of source code.

Hope that helps.